# How to interpret $F > F_{\rm crit}$, but $p > \alpha$

Tags: p-value, interpretation, f-test, f-distribution

My F is greater than F critical, while P-Value is 0.99 greater than alpha (0.05) which one should I consider the P value or F statistic, rejecting the Ho:

I am confused.

---

**Edit:**
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\textrm{F statistic} & \textrm{P-value} & \textrm{F crit} \\
 6.15E{-}7 & 0.999378168 & 4.084745733
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. Can you please edit your post and add the F values, the degrees of freedom and the P-value, so that we can understand better the background?

Comment: F            P-value        F crit
6.15E-07 0.999378168 4.084745733

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed the scientific notation. Note that:
$$
6.15E{-}07\; =\; 6.15\! \times\! 10^{-07}\; =\; 0{\Large .}000\ 000\ 615\; <\; 4.084745733
$$
So you should not reject $H_0$.